# PHP image upload and insert your path into database

Tags: php, file-upload, sql-insert

I have a bug with file's input. True, the image is moved into the server's folder - isset($_FILES['avatar']), is OK - but user_avatar's field isn't filled with your name. It's named with "default_130x130.png" on database. How should I do for send the "$user_avatar" variable, from upload_image.php, towards new_user.php?

---

en/users/new.html

```
    <form id="avatar_file_upload_form" action="../../utils/upload_image.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'style="position:absolute;z-index:-10;height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
        <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar_file_upload_field" accept="image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/bmp,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png"/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

---

utils/upload_image.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
$mimeExt = array();
$mimeExt['image/jpeg'] ='.jpg';
$mimeExt['image/pjpeg'] ='.jpg';
$mimeExt['image/bmp'] ='.bmp';
$mimeExt['image/gif'] ='.gif';
$mimeExt['image/x-icon'] ='.ico';
$mimeExt['image/png'] ='.png'; 
if(isset($_FILES["avatar"])) { 
     //Begins image upload
        $user_avatar = md5(uniqid(time())).$mimeExt[$_FILES["avatar"]["type"]]; //Get image extension
        $user_avatar_dir = "../img/".$user_avatar; //Path file
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], $user_avatar_dir); 

} else {
    $user_avatar = "default_130x130.png";
}
?>
```

---

new_user.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
include "config.php";
include "utils/upload_image.php";
$sql = mysql_query("insert into user(user_avatar) values('$user_avatar')", $db_connection) or die("Error: ".mysql_Error());
ob_end_clean();
mysql_close($db_connection);
?>
```

---

Note: the "config.php" file works perfectly.

Comment: Please make clear your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set your form's action attribute to `new_user.php`. Right now you're routing it to `upload_image.php` and I don't know how do you load `new_user.php` after that. You are actually including `upload_image.php` in `new_user.php` when there is no file sent to that page.

This should be your HTML:

```
<form id="avatar_file_upload_form" action="new_user.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'style="position:absolute;z-index:-10;height:1px;width:1px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar_file_upload_field" accept="image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/bmp,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This should be your `upload_image.php`:

```
<?php
$mimeExt = array();
$mimeExt['image/jpeg'] ='.jpg';
$mimeExt['image/pjpeg'] ='.jpg';
$mimeExt['image/bmp'] ='.bmp';
$mimeExt['image/gif'] ='.gif';
$mimeExt['image/x-icon'] ='.ico';
$mimeExt['image/png'] ='.png'; 
if(isset($_FILES["avatar"])) { 
     //Begins image upload
        $user_avatar = md5(uniqid(time())).$mimeExt[$_FILES["avatar"]["type"]]; //Get image extension
        $user_avatar_dir = "../img/".$user_avatar; //Path file
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], $user_avatar_dir); 

} else {
    $user_avatar = "default_130x130.png";
}
?>
```

And this should be your `new_user.php`:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include "config.php";
include "utils/upload_image.php";
$sql = mysql_query("insert into user(user_avatar) values('$user_avatar')", $db_connection) or die("Error: ".mysql_Error());
ob_end_clean();
mysql_close($db_connection);
?>
```

Comment: How Should I do for send the "$user_avatar" variable, from upload_image.php, towards new_user.php?

Comment: When you include a page in your file, it'll copy the exact content of that page to your file so you can have access to `$user_avatar`.

Comment: @AlexandreDória I've already answered you. I put the code for you.

Comment: Thanks, MahanGM. I created upload image.php only towards send the image name, after that any conditions be checked, like size, type, widht, height, etc..

Answer (score 0):

The form action is `utils/upload_image.php` the code and flow says that you need to set the form action to `new_user.php` file.

Also I'm not sure why the insert query works since the submission made to the `utils/upload_image.php` page and no relation is visible between `utils/upload_image.php` to `new_user.php`.. Your insert query shouldn't work in this case

**UPDATE:** for

> How Can I do true insert, so?

make your form go to new_user.php change the `action="../../new_user.php"`

```
<form id="avatar_file_upload_form" action="../../new_user.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'style="...">

</form>
```

Comment: How Can I do true insert, so?

Comment: Sure, @zzlalani! I created upload image.php only towards send the image name, after that any conditions be checked, like size, type, widht, height, etc.. Whatever, thanks.